# A question with Find the closest value in BST

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to write a function that takes in a BST and target integer value and returns the closest value to that target value contained in the BST.

However, My code is getting 0 instead of 10 which is answer for this case

can anyone explain underlying concept of my mistake?

```
    public static int findClosestValueInBst(BST tree, int target) {
        int globalDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int answer = 0;
        subFunction(tree, target, globalDiff, answer);
        return answer;
    }
```

```
private static void subFunction (BST tree, int target, int globalDiff, int answer) {
        if (tree == null) {
            return;
        }
        int localDiff = Math.abs(target - tree.value);
        if (localDiff < globalDiff) {
            globalDiff = localDiff;
            answer = tree.value;
        }
        subFunction(tree.left, target, globalDiff, answer);
        subFunction(tree.right, target, globalDiff, answer);
        return;
    }

    public static class BST {
        public int value;
        public BST left;
        public BST right;

        public BST(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BST first = new BST(1);
        BST second = new BST(2);
        BST third = new BST(10);
        BST fourth = new BST(5);
        BST fifth = new BST(4);

        first.left = second;
        first.right = third;
        second.left = fourth;
        second.right = fifth;

        System.out.println(findClosestValueInBst(first, 11));

    }
```

Comment: Java is pass by value, so it won't work if you want the value of `answer` in `subFunction` to be reflected in the return value of `findClosestValueInBst`

Comment: The tree generated in your main() is simply not a BST, in a BST, for each node x: `x.left < x  < x.right`, but in your case, for first: `first==1, first.left==2`.

Comment: Flaom's point also applies to `globalDiff` (it too must be a ref to reflect its value outside the function invocation). @amit: while the terminology is off (it's not a BST, as you say), the search code does not require the tree to be a BST.